# Object tracking using mobile devices

Tags: range-detector

We are creating a product that we would like to place a microchip into so that it can be easily found using an iPhone or android device.  The product we are creating is about the size of a small watch.

The radius we would need is up to 100m.
Precision needs to be within 1m.

We want to keep costs as low as possible because the product itself will be sold for around £5-10.

Does anyone know where I can start looking for manufacturers of this kind of tracking chip?

I have tried Alibaba but can't seem to find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to define this more in order to get a sensible answer. Over what range are you trying to locate the device? To what level of precision? What sort of battery life are you looking for / how much current consumption can you afford? What sort of price range are you looking at?

Comment: I have updated my question with a bit more info. Thanks

Comment: So you want a GPS-chip, some means of transferring the location to a phone with >100m range (bluetooth le?) and a processor - all the size of a watch and below £3 cost? Ambitious.

Comment: There are a lot of low power Bluetooth devices coming on the market that may be close to what you need, GPS positioning is impossible in your price range.  You can check out Amazon, eBay, KickStarter and others, the standards involved are AltBeacon, iBeacon and UriBeacon also check out an open source design at http://ruuvi.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your intention is to "find" the device, I am going to tell you how I would do this. Given your price point and wish for it to work (presumably without extra hardware) on an iPhone or Android device, I would put a microcontroller with built-in Bluetooth Smart (used to be called Bluetooth Low Energy) in your device to be found.

I would also include a buzzer or LED in your target device. In whatever app you have running on the phone, you have the ability to send a BT Smart message to your target device. When your target device receives the message, it beeps / flashes to help you find it.

Microcontrollers with BT Smart hardware built in are available from lots of different manufacturers including (but not limited to) Texas Instruments, NXP, Nordic Semiconductor, Microchip and Atmel.

Comment: Do you think this would be sufficient for my requirements? https://parts.arrow.com/item/detail/nordic-semiconductor/nrf51822-qfaa-t#nRgg

Comment: I really can't say for sure - it depends on what programming environment suits you, the exact details of your implementation and how this fits into the rest of your device design. I would generally recommend starting with a development kit if you are not sure and optimising towards production design from there - perhaps something like the [nRF51822 Bluetooth Smart Beacon Kit](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-Smart-Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF51822-Bluetooth-Smart-Beacon-Kit).